# How can draw a string using directX 10?

Tags: directx

I'm a newbie in directX and I have a problem with this.
I want to draw a string on the screen but it does not work. I did search on internet and I got some tutorials for this. This is the code:

```
//Create font
void RealGame::CreateMyFont(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddv)
{
D3DXCreateFont(d3ddv,    // the D3D Device
               20,    // font height
               0,    // default font width
               FW_NORMAL,    // font weight
               1,    // not using MipLevels
               false,    // italic font
               DEFAULT_CHARSET,    // default character set
               OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,    // default OutputPrecision,
               DEFAULT_QUALITY,    // default Quality
               DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,    // default pitch and family
               L"Arial",    // use Facename Arial
               &font);


}
//Draw text on screen
void RealGame::DrawGameInfo(LPD3DXSPRITE sp,LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddv,LPCWSTR text)
{
RECT textbox;
SetRect(&textbox, 100, 100, 800, 20);
D3DCOLOR fontColor = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0,0,255);  
if(font!=NULL)
    font->DrawText(sp, text, -1, &textbox, 0, fontColor );

}
```

The result is: no text displayed on screen.
Please tell me why and correct my mistakes if i have. 
Thank you.

UPDATE:
After change flag to DT_NOCLIP | DT_TOP | DT_LEFT
=> font->DrawText(sp, text, -1, &textbox, DT_NOCLIP | DT_TOP | DT_LEFT,, fontColor ); 
It works.
Thanks Gnietschow for help.

Comment: Are you calling sprit.Begin and End before and after? Checkout this [link](https://msmvps.com/blogs/mykre/archive/2007/11/28/xna-displaying-centred-text.aspx)

Comment: yes, I did,
SpriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
 DrawGameInfo(SpriteHandler,d3ddv,L"Text for test");
 SpriteHandler->End();

Comment: Have you tried to draw with the flags `DT_NOCLIP | DT_TOP | DT_LEFT`? Maybe it is clipped away, for whatever reasons. Moreover you could let sp null, only for testing.

Comment: OMG, you're my savior. It works ( use flag DT_NOCLIP | DT_TOP | DT_LEFT). Thank you so much.